# Open manifolds which have stable $\pi_1$ at infinity but are not inward tame

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a $1$-ended open manifold. An important result of Siebenmann states that (in dimension $\geq6$) if $M$ is $(i)$ inward tame, i.e. for every closed neighborhood of infinity there exists a homotopy which pulls it into a compact subset, $(ii)$ the end is pro-$\pi_1$ stable and $(iii)$ a certain obstruction vanishes, then the manifold is collarable, i.e. it admits a collar neighborhood of infinity (which is a neighborhood of the form $\partial N \times [0, +\infty)$). There are various papers, due mainly to Guilbault, Gu and their coauthors which try to understand what still holds if we drop the hypothesis $(ii)$ and try to replace it with softer conditions. On the other hand, I have not found any example of (say $1$-ended) manifolds whose end is indeed pro-$\pi_1$ stable but that are not inward tame: in fact, the only manifolds I know that are not inward tame are very far from being pro-$\pi_1$ stable (for example, the Whitehead manifold). Can you provide me any reference or examples?

Comment: Any inward tame open manifold has finitely many ends, see e.g. proposition 3.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304031.pdf. Is there an open manifold manifold with infinitely many ends such that each end has stable fundamental group at infinity?

Comment: Oh, I see that you want a one-ended space. Without this assumption take the complement of a countable closed subset $C$ of $S^3$ with a single accumulation point $p$. Then I think every end of $S^3\setminus C$ has trivial fundamental group. For the end corresponding to $p$ this is true because any path-homotopy can be pushed off $C$. For the other ends triviality is obvious.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Yes, I was looking for a 1-ended space. I think as well that the example you provided works, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the motivations of having inward tameness is one wants to guarantee the manifold is finitely dominated, which is the condition Wall needs to establish his obstruction. Having this condition ensures the homology at infinity is finitely generated. Without that, we may have examples like the one given in [Guilbault's survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.6741.pdf)[Ex. 3.5.11, P. 35].

[image]
[image]